# EclipseLink OneToOne mapping error

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, weblogic, eclipselink

I have set up 3 classes. `ClassA` has FK of `ClassB` and `ClassC` respectively. I have put up the following lines in my `ClassA`

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="ClassA")
    public class ClassA{
    //rest of the code

        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=ClassB.class)
        @JoinColumn(name="ClassB_ColA", columnDefinition="ClassB_ColA", updatable=false, insertable=false)
        private ClassB classB;

        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=ClassC.class)
        @JoinColumn(name="ClassC_ColA", columnDefinition="ClassC_ColA", updatable=false, insertable=false)
        private ClassC classC;
}
```

and i am getting following exception

```
Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [_persistence_set_classB_vh] or [_persistence_get_classB_vh] is not defined in the object [project.persistence.entities.ClassA].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: project.persistence.entities.ClassA._persistence_get_classB_vh()
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[classB]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(project.persistence.entities.ClassA --> [DatabaseTable(ClassA)])
```

I did a little bit search and i could find some [old threads](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg03432.html) saying about waving static loading or something. Can someone suggest a solution ?

P.S:
I am using weblogic 10 and eclipselink2

Comment: Your column definition is wrong. Have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html).

Comment: How is this wrong? i am using `OntToOne` mapping not `manyToOne`

Comment: @siebz0r duplicate Class B in your Class A.

Comment: Have you defined the getters for thos properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to static wavingo f the objects. So what i did that i changed the loading mechanism.

From `ClassB`, i didn't load anything for `ClassA` and for `ClassA`, I kept the lazy loading .. and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about considering duplicated by copy paste attribute names?

```
..
private ClassB classB;
..
private ClassB classB;
```